# ¿Como puedo mostrar un campo con varios resultados en una columna MySQL por PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una duda estoy queriendo mostrar el campo **armas** de la tabla **cl_datos**

[image: La columna armas es la que quiero para obtener el dato]

Por ej: en el campo **armas** esta escrito de la siguiente forma:

- **0 / 0 / 0 / 0 / 0 / 0 / 0**
- (Knife / M4 / Deagle / Awp / Glock / Ak / Usp)

El primer **0** proviene de las **KNIFE** cuando un jugador adquiere una Knife nueva aumenta +1
en la posición del 0 del arma obtenida. En este caso seria -> (**1** 0 0 0 0 0 0)

[image: El 0 que se encuadra en verde es de las knife]

Entonces lo que yo quiero que se muestre en el `<span></span>` seria el arma con skin seria Knife = 1 Skin | M4 = 0 Skin.

```php
<div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="general">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            KNIFE
            <span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill"><?php echo $player_ffa->armas ?></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Otra duda es que en las columnas **KNIFES** / **M4** / **DEAGLE** / **AWP** / **GLOCK** / **AK** / **USP**

También es lo mismo cambiando que en estas columnas muestran las SKIN de estas armas por ej:

> El primer skin proviene del primer **0**
>
> El segundo skin proviene del segundo **0** y así.
>
> Al obtener una SKIN el **0** se cambia por **1**

[image: Los primeros 0 pertenecen al primer skin, luego el segundo 0 pertenece a la segunda skin]

Tengo las imágenes de las skin de las knife por ej:

```php
$skin = [
        'https://screenshots.gamebanana.com/img/ss/skins/50c78dacc887c.jpg',
        'https://files.gamebanana.com/img/ss/skins/55ce2533e3571.jpg',
];

<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
  SKIN
  <?php echo '<img src="' . $skins[$player_ffa->Knifes - 0] . '">'; ?>
</li>
```

No me esta mostrando los resultados que quiero.

Desde ya agradezco cualquier ayuda que se le pueda dar.

Comment: No logro entender tu pregunta. ¿Los datos en la columna `armas` estás guardados tal cual, como varios `0` con espacio?

Comment: @A.Cedano Exacto, cuando llamo a la columna me da todos los resultados en vez de uno solo que es el arma que quiero saber cuanta skin tiene por ej:

Columna armas -> 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 (Solo quiero que se muestre el primer 1 es decir que la knife tiene 1 skin).

No se si se puede entender.

Comment: Es que entonces tienes un problema muy serio de diseño. Imagino que necesitarás esa información para más cosas, como por ejemplo para saber cuántas armas tiene,  cuanto suma el total de armas, etc. Si guardas los datos así cualquier cálculo o cualquier presentación de los datos se te va a complicar (como de hecho parece que ya ocurre aquí). Creo que lo correcto sería reflejar la colección de armas de otro modo, para ello habrá que crear más tablas, relaciones entre tablas, etc.

Comment: Gracias por tu sugerencia, el tema que no se mucho de MySQL y relacionar entre tablas como seria? Si puedes compartir una guía seria de mucha ayuda!

Comment: Por ejemplo, si de un valor como este: `1 0 0 0 0 0 0` quieres obtener únicamente el `1` puedes recurrir a procedimientos algo complicados y poco seguros como usar `explode` basándote en el espacio en blanco, pero eso es muy chapucero, porque puede que los datos no siempre respeten normas como que haya un solo espacio entre cada cifra (el usuario pudo teclear uno o más espacios por error en alguna introducción de datos y ese pequeño error ya rompe toda la lógica que implementes). Aún así, cuando llegue el momento de hacer estadísticas ese modelo de datos no te ayudará para nada.

Comment: Realmente la tengo complicada, pero bueno, tendré que pasar todo a una tabla como usted dice :/

Comment: Realmente uno de los principios de las bases de datos es que son *relacionales*. Es un concepto amplio que no se podría explicar siquiera en una respuesta. Para resumir, puedes tener varias tablas que compartan datos comunes identificados por una columna en común que suele ser el `ID`. Un caso típico serían los países, provincias, ciudades. Las relaciones se manejarían en tres tablas donde por medio de IDs determinarías que: una provincia pertenece a un país, y por otro ID que una ciudad pertenece a una provincia. Las relaciones pueden ser extensas e implicar más cosas. En tu caso...

Comment: ... habría quizá una tabla `armas`, otra tabla `armas_jugador` y sería en `armas_jugador` donde expresarías qué armas tiene cada jugador mediante su `ID`. La cuestión es que aquí el modelo es flexible. Imagina que cada arma tiene una potencia específica, eso sería expresado en la tabla `armas` y si quieres calcular el total de potencia de un jugador en armas, en base a la info en `armas_jugador` harías una consulta de suma y lo obtendrías. Lo mismo para los valores que indicas como `0 0 0 0`, en una sola fila actualmente. Esos valores no existirían hasta que el jugador no tuviese una arma ...

Comment: ...realmente. Es decir, actualmente en tu modelo de datos son incluso valores ficticios que no hacen nada ahí, sólo ocupar espacio. Un jugador tendría un arma realmente cuando ésta tuviese un valor (`1` o más). Si se trata de inicializar un jugador con `X` cantidad de armas que no tiene ningún valor también se podría hacer, pero no tiene sentido desde un punto de vista real. En fin, te recomiendo que leas un poco sobre bases de datos relacionales, te ayudará mucho en la programación, no sólo a facilitar las cosas, sino a escribir un programa robusto y flexible.

Comment: Mira para que puedas entrar en detalles, el juego es CS 1.6 todo los jugadores tienen acceso a todas las armas, pero no a las SKIN, cuando sube de ELO/Nivel estos tienen acceso a esa Arma y es ahí cuando se desbloquea la SKIN, que quiero decir que donde está el 0, se cambia por el 1, para que relativamente le diga al juego que esa SKIN tal jugador la ha desbloqueado y todo por ID del juegor.

Comment: En mis comentarios he puesto ejemplos imaginarios para que entiendas la importancia del modelo relacional. En el modelo irían todas las tablas, también la tabla `skin`, los `niveles` , etc. Y en el modelo expresas las reglas de juego combinando con lógica de programación. Por ejemplo, ¿de qué manera bloqueas ciertas armas a las que se puede acceder solo a partir del nivel 2? Si implementas un  modelo de datos robusto eso es pan comido. Pero si metes todo en una tabla, al final se te hace un lío tremendo. Además las cosas evolucionan, imagina que se incluye un arma nueva ...

Comment: ... o un nivel nuevo o un skin nuevo. Todo eso en un modelo relacional bien diseñado puede implementarse sin dificultad ninguna. Cuando diseñas una base de datos y escribes un programa tienes que pensar también en eso, en futuras evoluciones, en futuros datos que te pueden pedir. Imagina que te piden una estadísticas de: qué jugador de nivel 2 ha ganado más armas de tal tipo, o qué jugador ha perdido el juego debido a ataques con el arma de tal tipo. Hay estadísticas complicadas que te pueden pedir dentro de 1 mes y que podrían poner a prueba seriamente tu modelo de datos si no está bien hecho

Comment: La verdad interesante punto de vista, no lo pensé así, creo que tendre que poner a practicar lo de las bases de datos relacionales y poner en practica. Me he quedado en el tiempo. Agradezco por su tiempo para explicarme y ayudarme a entender sobre base de datos.

Comment: De nada. Te sugiero que empieces poco a poco, por lo básico de la relación  y luego vayas profundizando. En la medida en que entras en el tema irás aprendiendo y si tienes dudas las puedes plantear aquí. Si es un entorno de juego, lo básico sería empezar con una tabla `jugador` y otra tabla  `combate` por ejemplo, donde se enfrentan los jugadores. Así vas ampliando las tablas y las relaciones. Si empiezas por relaciones complicadas sin entender cómo funciona rápidamente te perderías y desanimarías.

Comment: Disculpa @A.Cedano tengo un problema de seguridad que recién he notado, no tiene que ver con respecto a esto pero si lo planteo aquí me ayudarías? Creo que es algo menos complejo, o creo otro tema para que pueda tener mas ayuda? Esta basado en $_GET a la hora de mostrar las ID de los Jugadores, si se manipula la URL arroja error.

Comment: Es mejor que lo plantées en una nueva pregunta. Así será más visibles y podrás tener respuesta de uno o más usuarios. Siempre es mejor varios puntos de vista.

Comment: @JoaqhoC te dejo un link que plantea de manera sencilla el manejo de bases de datos relacionales, partiendo de ahi creo que puedes crecer tu BD a las necesidades de tu juego.  https://www.ionos.mx/digitalguide/hosting/cuestiones-tecnicas/bases-de-datos-relacionales/

Comment: Muchas gracias @Cesarin